# Can synchronous data transfer be used for transferring large data in case of computer architecture and organization?

Tags: computer-architecture, computer-networks

I am learning computer architecture and organization.

> I have this confusion, can synchronous data transfer be used for transferring large data in case of computer architecture and organization?

I have read that synchronous data transfer can be used for transferring large data but I think it is true only in case of computer networks, in case of computer architecture and organization I think DMA is used for transferring large data. So if someone asks me if synchronous data transfer be used for transferring large data in case of computer architecture and organization. Should I say yes or no?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the question has no clear answer. Data can be transferred in a synchronous or asynchronous manner. Each has its own pros and cons. Synchronous communication is irrelevant for some systems, e.g., when there is no joint clock or where the distance causes too large clock skews. Both methods are capable of transferring large amounts of data. For instance, USB is kinda asynchronous, in the sense it has no clock (it uses synchronization strings to maintain synchronization) and yet it is capable of transferring large amount of data.

DMA is a mechanism within some chip that allows transferring data (small amount or large amount) without the involvement of the CPU. Within a chip most communication is synchronous (there are exceptions). However, the DMA communication might have gaps within its transmissions as the BUS might be needed for the CPU. It might depend on the exact mode of DMA operation.